# Node.js button link to page in the same folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js, how do you link to another page in the same folder like you can with html?  I tried the following code to link to `thankyou.ejs` file in the same folder, it doesn't seem to work

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="thankyou.ejs" role="button">Submit</a>
```

Comment: Seems like you need to use the include directive. Explained here: <https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will have to create a route to `thankyou`. Remember you don't link pages, rather a route.

Suppose your server looks like this:

```
// server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// use res.render to load up an ejs view file

// index page
app.post('/thankyou', function(req, res) {
  res.render('pages/thankyou');
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Server is listening on port 8080');
```

Then you can easily refer to the page as:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="thankyou" role="button">Submit</a>
```